# Assign certain editors to certain posts

Tags: posts

I am using the backend in wordpress and plugin ACF to make a pupil management system for a home tuition service.

As you can see in the image I have turned the "posts" into "pupils":

[image]

I have teachers who are registered as "editors". When the editors login at the moment they can see all the pupils. I only want them to be able to see their pupils.

My question is how do I assign editors to specific posts so they can only access and edit posts they have been assigned to?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you used author, instead of editor, then WP default functionality would be such that they could only see those posts they are listed as author on. Editor might be then used for something like a supervisor who doesn't need other admin roles.

This solution means you don't have to modify anything and can use the roles the way they were designed.

Is it possible you could switch up the role you have assigned them to author?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that makes sense but i'll need to be able to assign multiple authors as the pupils are shared by different teachers. I found the plugins "User Permission" and SP Authors, but sadly they are no longer supported and do not work. Any ideas how I can assign multiple authors?

Comment: Have you seen this <http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin> - Justin's stuff is usually pretty good but I have not used this one. This is a fairly complex task you are asking to do so if this plugin, or any other do the trick, I think that would be your best option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Link is broken though

Comment: If anyone else has a similar issue, I did as NickJAB suggested and switched to authors. I used the plugin Co-Author Plus which is a fork of sp-author and User Role Editor. With the two plugins I was able to allocate authors to specific posts.

Comment: This was the appropriate link just for your reference (the system added a carat to the end http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin

Comment: Also, since you used my author suggestion, could you mark my answer as the appropriate one? I'm trying to get enough reputation to comment on other people's posts (darn rules) lol

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used Co-authors Plus http://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/

and

User Role Editor http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

I disallowed authors from editing other peoples posts with User Role Editor and editors can assign users to posts using Co-author Plus.